Adding big O notation with one constant
There are many posts on adding big O notation when one of the values does not converge (say $n^4$).
I am confused about how to put two things together when one diverges very slowly $O(\ln^2(n))$ and the other is a constant, say -1.
In summary, the question is how to write $f(n) -1- O(\log^4 n)$. Is it simply $f(n) - O(\log^4 n)$?

Is $1$ eventually dominated by some constant multiple of $\log^4(n)$?

Yes, $\lim_n 1/\log^4 n = 0$, so that $1 = O(\log^4 n)$.
